# How to add custom headers when using Spring+websocket+stomp

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

Is it possible to add custom header from server side?
I tried to add an interceptor to outboundchannel, but couldn't add any custom header.
By the way my question is absolutely the same as 3 years ago from Glinskiy Vladislav: [How to add custom headers to STOMP CREATED message in Spring Boot application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166472/how-to-add-custom-headers-to-stomp-created-message-in-spring-boot-application).
But there is still no answer with a solution.